# Checking 2 JComboboxes is empty or not in Java

Tags: java, swing

[image]

I have created above form with editable auto suggesting Combo boxes that retrieves data from MySQL database.
These two combo boxes  have connected functionality as,
**If one combo box select an item or get typed item, the matching or relevant item from the database shows in the other combo box.**

I wrote some code for checking,when I click the find button

1. **If both Combo boxes are empty** - shows "at least give ID or Name massage
2. **If any one of these combo box is empty** - shows "no such supplier in the database" because one combo box is empty means no such record in database.

Scenario 1 is working fine but the 2<sup>nd</sup> scenario is not working (If I fill both combo boxes shows the 2<sup>nd</sup> scenario).

My code for find button action performed;

```
private void find_btnActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (IDcombo.getItemCount() == 0 && Namecombo.getItemCount() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Please enter at least one of Item ID or Item Name..." );
    } else if (IDcombo.getItemCount() == 0 || Namecombo.getItemCount() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "There are no supplier details as given...");
    } else {
        String sname = (String) Namecombo.getSelectedItem();
        try {
            SupplierView view = new SupplierView();
            view.getSName(sname);
            this.dispose();
            view.setVisible(true);
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InventoryManagementeditList.class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you fill just one box number 2 scenario happens?

Comment: yes if any one combo box is empty, I want to show "There are no suppliers as given " @Jure

Comment: If you don't shove result if there is not data in both combo boxs, coulden't you then just remove that else if?
If first if works, then second should also work, I can't see the error :/
You could try and at start of the function output count for both elements, so that you see if they are really 0.

Comment: Can't you just debug and see what happend in the method?

Comment: I can't remove else if part. I edited the question..@Jure

Comment: @tenten I understand now how it works. But you should try to debug check what is IDcombo.getItemCount() and Namecombo.getItemCount() when event is fired.